# how much traffic iOS Maps using while in turn-by-turn navigation mode?

Tags: ipad, cellular-data

I'm trying to estimate necessary data plan for a Euro trip, and my main concern is: I'm going to use an iPad mini native Maps app for turn-by-turn navigation being there. Was unsuccessfully trying to find out how much traffic driving let's say from Prague to Berlin (it is a 3-4 hours trip) might use.

I understand I can pre-load/cache some maps for the route while I'm still on wifi at the starting point. But I feel that is very unreliable approach, and it's better to be able to have cellular data plan activated for the entire trip. AT&T (my device is used with AT&T in the U.S.) sells [300MB of international data plan for $60](http://www.att.com/att/global/affordable-world-packages/?data). If let's say I'm considering not buying local SIM with local data plan in Europe, is there a way to predict/estimate how much data plan traffic a 3-4 hours trip through Europe might consume? And how much driving time those 300MB will buy me.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, not much:

> My 20min 6 mile commute this morning used up about 150KB. Which could have been just traffic.

<sup>Source: http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=15684662&postcount=6</sup>

This is without flyover and using standard maps (without satellite view).